# Getting a reference to a Node module and work with it in a separate thread

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node-modules

Assuming I have 2 different sources:

1. `node_module.cc`
2. `threaded_class.cc`

`node_module.cc` is where I am calling *`NODE_MODULE`* to initialize my module. This module has a function that makes an instance of *`threaded_class.cc`* (**in a separate thread**). I understand that I need to use Lockers and Isolates to access v8 in a separate thread but my issue is bigger than that.

*`NODE_MODULE`* function is my only chance to catch the module's instance from my understanding. [I found this article](http://bravenewmethod.com/2011/03/30/callbacks-from-threaded-node-js-c-extension/) that uses a piece of code that is what I am exactly looking for. The author stores the module handle in a persistent object like this:

```
auto module_handle = Persistent<Object>::New(target);
```

But this either seems deprecated or not possible anymore. However I figured that it can be achieved like this:

```
auto module_handle = Persistent<Object>(context->GetIsolate() ,target);
```

However the latter, when I am trying to access its properties, are mostly private methods and properties, nothing worth to be used or I am not knowing how to use this.

My question is, is there any updated guide on how to properly handle these kind of stuff in writing a Node module? Or can you show me an example how I can pass my latter *`module_handle`* to my thread and use it for example for executing a js function called *`test`*?

I also want to know, what is the difference between `NODE_MODULE` and `NODE_MODULE_CONTEXT_AWARE` when initializing a node module?

Comment: What's the reason for needing access to `target` in your `threaded_class`?

Comment: @mscdex `threaded_class` needs to check if a certain js function exists in `target`. or Invoking a certain js function in `target`.

Comment: I'm not sure about node v0.11+, but in v0.10 I've found there is no way to get at node's isolate and get a lock on it in order to use the v8 context in a separate thread. What I've done instead is used `uv_async_send()` from the thread to signal the main thread to do something in node's v8 context.